# Undelete utility that preserves folder structure

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, file-recovery

I did a dumb thing and now need to undelete some files.  In fact, I have already recovered the files using [Glary Undelete](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/glary-undelete/), which has served me well on the other rare occasions where this has been necessary.  So I have the files.

The problem is that Glary and the [other undelete options I've looked at](https://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows/238356#238356) don't preserve the original folder structure.  In this case I have about 3,000 small files that I must match to their original locations in a complex nested folder hierarchy.  I could see the full folder paths in Glary before the restore, so I know the information is there; it's just not using that information and copying everything to root of my designated destination, rather than relative to the original location.

Comment: I have had best results with [iCare Data Recovery](http://www.icare-recovery.com/compare.html). Smooth UI, very fast, recover folders as such, and searchable output. I missed the last one in most undelete tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to preserve the folder structure with [Pandora Recovery](http://www.pandorarecovery.com/).

Comment: McAfee says PandoraRecovery (PandoraRecovery-42151231.exe) contains a trojan horse

Answer (score 1):

No.  Files are deleted by removing their reference from the directory index.  The file still exists on the disk (until the space it occupies is overwritten) but there is no longer a reference to tell the restore software which directory it was in.

The trash/recycle bin of modern OSes remembers where the file was before it was moved so it can be restored correctly.

Backup utilities like TimeMachine store a mirrored copy of the file system so that they know were each file was.

Comment: Thing is, the undelete software I used first showed me the original path in the user interface before I started the recovery - it had the information there somehow.

Comment: I think it may depend on the file system in use.  IIRC, FAT based drives "delete" a file by chaining it's name in the directory to have a space as the first character.  In this case, the directory info is available but the first character of the name is not.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Directory_table